# SpringBoot: How to make profile specific resources

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have profiles: dev, prod.

And my homepage located at `/src/main/resources/static/index.html`

How to make different homepage with different profile?

For example, `/src/main/resources/static-dev/index.html` and `/src/main/resources/static-prod/index.html`.

Any advice?

Comment: You write an an action handler (`@GetMapping` method) for `/index.html` that selects the "view" to show.

Comment: @Andreas How to route the js and css files. I have some code like this `<script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script>`, the app.js is different.

Comment: Why would `.../static-dev/index.html` include `/app.js` if it needs `/app.js` a `dev` version? But you could always do the same for .js and .css files, i.e. create `@GetMapping` handlers.

Comment: For example, we have a web manager system deploy at `www.ninja.com/manager/index.html`, and `dev.ninja.com/manager/index.html` And we use restful api to connect with the data, the restful host are different, and hard coded at app.js file.So we want to separate both of them. Finally I got a solution, use `spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static-dev/` in application.properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I got a simple solution.

Use different config file `application.properties` and `application-prod.properties`.

Each of them I config a different resource location. For example `spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static-dev/`.

Comment: A workable solution but I'd suggest going with environment variables if you can get it to work. Using ENVs integrate better with cloud pipeline promotions and you're less likely to forget to update a particular configuration.

Comment: @TanKimLoong I think this solution is already [profile specific](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html). `spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static/,classpath:/static-dev/` in `application-dev.properties`, and `spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static/,classpath:/static-prod/` in `application-prod.properties`. Run with the script `java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=prod xxx.jar` with active the profile

Comment: You're already achieving what you want to achieve. That's great. I'm just suggesting that you might want to check out ENVs so that in the future when you need to let's say add staging and UAT properties you don't have to create separate properties. Set the ENVs on different machine instead. 1 property, multiple ENV. Of course, you can have multiple properties on all environments. but I find it weird to find application-dev.properties on a production machine/artefact. It doesn't break things though, so it's not a major concern

Comment: I have a question, what if you want a change to a file in a resource location and want the change be done in other resources too? Is there a way that change be done from one resource in other resources too? @Ninja

Comment: hello @user5621266 I am not clear on your question. I met the problem is how to make dev homepage's title is 'dev-foobar', and production homepage's title is 'foobar', make some difference in those environment. Finally I use the solution mentioned above.

Comment: this is my question in detail: @Ninja
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58197181/change-a-file-that-is-same-in-all-profiles?noredirect=1#comment102772772_58197181

Comment: What if I want different SQL Scripts for different profiles? Then How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If your project supports the Maven dependency manager, [Maven's build profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) may be able to help you:

```
<profile>
    <id>live</id>
    <properties>
        <environment>live</environment>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/${environment}</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</profile>
```

The code above should be in your `pom.xml`. In your Spring properties you can specify the active profile in one line:

```
spring.profiles.active=live
```

This should be enough to conditionally load any resources.

Comment: A word `prod` would be better than `live`.

Answer (score 1):

Both resources should be put under `/src/main/resources/static` (since this is the default static resource folder IIRC) and then categorized into `/prod` and `/dev`. Then in your `@GetMapping` controller, choose to return `/prod/index` or `/dev/index` based on your condition

Comment: And how to deal the css and js files, write the controller to dispatch is not graceful.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to include resources based on profile. You can, however, injecting a different controller bean controlled by `@Profile` annotation. 

```
@Controller
@Profile("dev")
public class DevController {

}
```

Comment: I change the default static location in application.properties. i.e spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static-dev/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [`Filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) that changes the request URL from `/index.html` to `/dev/index.html` or `/prod/index.html` as needed.

The filter can also do the `/dev` or `/prod` prefixing for `.css` and `.js` files.

Unless *all* your files are split between `dev` and `prod`, you'd probably need an explicit list of which requests should be prefixed.

Comment: An interesting alternative. Never thought of that but unless if that `Filter` is turned off in production it will incur some overhead albeit probably minimal. Something to look out for. Probably more confusing for new joiners when they don't realize adding a test controller requires adding it to `Filter` before they work.