# Change a file that is same in all profiles?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I have four profiles which differ in static files. Should I have four different resources to switch between them? Then What if we want to change one of the files that is same in all resorces? Should we change all four resources files?
If I want to explain more, consider you want to change index.html file for all profiles but have different login.html file for each profile. Now I have four static profiles like dev-static, prod-static and ... . Is there any way I don't change all four index.html file that have the same change?

Comment: why don't you use one application yaml file, where you can add common properties and profile specific properties as well. Or you can create `application.properties` file for properties common across profiles and create `application-<profile>.properties` for profile specific properties. Disadvantage is you will endup with 5 properties files in your case. So yaml is better option

Comment: my problem is not different properties but change in a file that same in all profiles, I updated my question, please check again. @pvpkiran

Comment: Do you mean you want a single file called 'index.html' but 4 different 'login.html' depends on the environment ? I think this config may help you `spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static-core,classpath:/static-dev`,  `spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static-core,classpath:/static-prod` and .... Put the 'index.html' in /static-core, and 'login.html' in 4 different directories. It's untested, please take a try~

Comment: No, we don't know which file is going to change commonly in all profiles to put it in a separate location. we may something in login.html in one of profiles change and want that changed be done in other login.html files too. @Ninja

Comment: So you do not know which file will be going to change in compile time, and you only  know it in run time?

Comment: No, it is not an issue of compile or run time. you said you can put common files in a directory called static-core. But I'm saying It is not determined which file is going to change for all profiles to put it in static-core. Maybe a file in a Profile has a change that should happen for all other profiles too.